# Differences between .call(this) and () on a immediately self invoking function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, self-invoking-function

I came across this code in one of our online AngularJS apps, and was wondering what this does. Is it different than just calling a immediately self invoking function with parenthesis.

```
(function() {

}).call(this); // What was in TFS
```

vs

```
(function() {

})(); // Are these the same?
```

Is there any benefits of calling one over the other, or is it merely coding preference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're very different. The first uses whatever the current `this` is (at global scope, `this` is a reference to the global object; in other scopes, it could be just about anything). The second will use the default `this`, which is a reference to the global object in loose mode but `undefined` in strict mode.

Gratuitous example :-) :

```js
console.log("At global scope:");
(function() {
  console.log(this === window); // true
}).call(this); // What was in TFS
(function() {
  console.log(this === window); // true
})();
(function() {
  "use strict";
  console.log(this === window); // false (this === undefined)
})();

console.log("Not at global scope:");
(function() {
  (function() {
    console.log(this === window); // false
  }).call(this); // What was in TFS
  (function() {
    console.log(this === window); // true
  })();
}).call({});// Using something other than the default
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: I see. So putting `"use strict";` **Before**  the immediately self invoking function will also cause `this === undefined`?

Comment: @JustinJmnz: `"use strict"` can only be used at the beginning of a scope. But yes, functions defined in strict-mode code are also strict.

Comment: @JustinJmnz: My first sentence in the answer was utterly and completely wrong. I've fixed it. :-) (I was forgetting about the possibility of putting `"use strict"` at the top of your global code.)